# c++ exception safety

Tags: c++, exception

Exceptional C++ mentions the following code

```
template <class T> class Stack 
{
    public:
      Stack();
      ~Stack();

      /*...*/

    private:
       T*     v_;      // ptr to a memory area big
       size_t vsize_;  //  enough for 'vsize_' T's
       size_t vused_;  // # of T's actually in use
};



template<class T> 
Stack<T>::Stack()
        : v_(new T[10]),  // default allocation
          vsize_(10),
          vused_(0)       // nothing used yet
{ 
}
```

It says that If one of the T constructors threw, then any T objects that were fully constructed were properly destroyed and, finally, operator delete was automatically called to release the memory. That makes us leakproof.

My understanding was that if a constructor throws an exception, the application should cleanup any allocated resources.  How is the above leakproof?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting the C++03 standard, §5.3.4/8:

> A *new-expression* obtains storage for the object by calling an *allocation function*. If the *new-expression* terminates by throwing an exception, it may release storage by calling a deallocation function. If the allocated type is a non-array type, the allocation function’s name is `operator new` and the deallocation function’s name is `operator delete`. If the allocated type is an array type, the allocation function’s name is `operator new[]` and the deallocation function’s name is `operator delete[]`.

§5.3.4/17:

> If any part of the object initialization described above terminates by throwing an exception and a suitable deallocation function can be found, the deallocation function is called to free the memory in which the object was being constructed, after which the exception continues to propagate in the context of the *new-expression*.

Consequently, if any `T` constructor throws an exception, the runtime will destroy any already-created subobjects of the `T` instance whose constructor threw, then call `operator delete[]` on the array as a whole, destroying any already-created elements and deallocating the array's memory.

Comment: Makes you wonder how well the implementations work: if the constructor for `v_[5]` threw, then would `delete v_[]` only destroy `v_[0]` through `v_[4]`, and skip the ones not constructed?

Comment: @Mike : The ones not constructed don't need to be destroyed (they were never created); what are you saying the problem is?

Comment: I'm wondering if it goes and destroys them anyway. (I.e. does it lose track of how many it successfully constructed?) Now that I think about it, I wonder if it guarantees destruction in reverse order of construction...

Comment: @Mike : The standard has all those points covered (still in §5.3.4), but it's far too long to copy here in its entirety. :-] Specifically, no, it doesn't attempt to destroy objects that weren't constructed; and yes, they are destroyed in reverse order of construction.

Comment: OK, then as long as the implementation follows the standard on those points, koobi's code is good.

Comment: @Mike: Only destructors of (constructed) objects are called, but the entire allocated memory (which had been allocated before any constructors were called in the first place) is freed using `::operator delete[]()`.

Comment: This would be great, but I'm not _entirely_ convinced that the quoted snippets really mean what you say they mean. In particular, though the space for the array will be freed, I'm not convinced that destructors for already-constructed `T` subobjects will be invoked, and thus there would be possible leaks. This would be a _horrendous_ issue in the standard, so I'm not going to outright claim it to be the case. I simply don't think that the quoted paragraphs are sufficient to answer this question.

Comment: @Tomalak : It says specifically that `operator delete[]` will be invoked on the array -- you're questioning whether `operator delete[]` destroys the elements of the array? O_o

Comment: @ildjarn: If this rule were followed verbatim, after element `x` of an array of `N` elements failed construction, then `N-x` non-existent objects would be being destructed. Do you think that this is the case? [disclaimer: I may have an off-by-one in this comment; I don't care :D]

Comment: @Tomalak: Uh, you're asking what I asked, and he said (fourth comment) that it's covered "in §5.3.4), but it's far too long to copy here in its entirety." So, yes, it's covered, but no, not by the quoted parts in the answer.

Comment: @Tomalak : The only additional standard citation I can think of that may be relevant is §3.7.4: "*The storage duration of member subobjects, base class subobjects and array elements is that of their complete object*". It's a bit hand-wavy, but I can't come up with anything better right now. ;-[

Comment: @Mike: I wasn't so much re-asking what was asked, as disputing that this answer answers it. If a piece of that clause covers the question and wasn't quoted, then sorry I haven't gotten around to looking up the full clause. Then again, if the relevant text wasn't quoted in this answer, then this is _not_ an answer.

Comment: @ildjarn: That certainly comes close, I guess! It is indeed a bit wiffly, but I suppose it fits... :/

Comment: @Tomalak : Ultimately I believe the relevant text _is_ quoted here; if you're looking for a full dissertation on why the OP's code is leak-proof, you may want to read the book the OP got the code from in the first place, as it dedicates at least a full chapter to explaining this in detail. But as far as the standard is concerned, this is the entirety of the relevant text as far as I know.

Comment: I hate to say it, but I think we've been chasing the wrong issue. If one of the `T` constructors throws, we're golden, but if `v_` gets completely constructed, then something else in `Stack<T>::Stack()` throws, there's no destructor for a `T*`, so `v_` is leaked. `Stack<T>::~Stack()` wouldn't get called since the constructor didn't finish. So you have to use a smart pointer of some form, or you have to put in a `try` block to catch exceptions in the constructor code and `delete [] v_;` before rethrowing. In the OP's example, this isn't an issue because there's no code there to throw anything.

Comment: @Mike : That's true, and is what Kerrek's answer addresses. However, the OP is asking about this code _specifically_ since the book he got it from claims it is canonically exception-safe, and he didn't understand why it's so.

Answer (score 3):

[Correction:] <s>It is not.</s> An exception in your constructor won't leak resources because the only place an exception could occur is inside the `new` expression, and if a `new` expression fails, the resources that were allocated by it are freed. *Your situation is special because you only make one single allocation in the constructor -- in general this is not safe!*

Your quoted phrase refers to is the delete operator for the failed-object whose constructor threw:

```
struct T
{
  T() { throw 1; }
  char data[200];
};

// in your code:

T * pt = new T;
```

In the last line, memory is allocated before the constructor is invoked. *That* memory is released in the event of an exception, by an automatic call to `::operator delete(pt)`. (In general, the matching delete-operator (not "expression"!) matching the new expression is called.)

It goes like this:

- Successful construction: 1. Allocation. 2. Construction. 3. Destruction. 4. Deallocation.
- Unsuccessful construction: 1. Allocation. 2. Deallocation.

Note that we only *have* an object *after* the constructor has completed -- so in the event of an exception in the constructor, *we do not even have an object*. That's why I said "failed-object" above with a hyphen, because it's not an object at all (like the Douglas-fir isn't a fir at all).

Your code is potentially entirely leak *unsafe*, if you are making more than one allocation which could throw - i.e. a leak occurs whenever one object has been successfully constructed but another, subsequent one fails. You should probably just not call `new` in the initializer list and instead put it in the body:

```
class Danger
{
  T * pt1, * pt2;
public:
  Danger()
  {
    try { pt1 = new T; } catch(...) { throw(); }
    try { pt2 = new T; } catch(...) { delete pt1; throw(); }
  }
};
```

Or, by the principle of single responsibility, don't use raw pointers but use resource managing containers that clean up after themselves!!

Comment: I entirely disagree, but I'm hesitant to downvote because you're generally a pretty smart fella. ;-] In light of the standardese quoted in my answer, do you really think the OP's code can leak?

Comment: I don't understand how char data[] is being destroyed.

Comment: @ildjarn: Check my update; the actual code in the OP is possibly fine, but as soon as you add anything to the constructor that could throw, you're in trouble. The only thing that's protected against leaking is the object itself.

Comment: @Code Monkey: `data` is automatic, so it gets destroyed automatically.

Comment: @Kerrek : More to the point, the code in the OP is _definitely_ fine. Your point stands that any further non-POD subobjects' constructors may throw, causing a leak, but the question (as I read it) was about _that_ code specifically, so I don't think your answer should imply that it isn't leak-proof.

Comment: @Kerrek: I understand that `data` is automatic. I was trying to understand your comment about delete, like it was in a destructor.

Comment: @ildjarn: It's definitely *far* from leak-proof: anything in the `/* ... */` might thrown and leave you with a leak. OK, the constructor *as written* at the moment is fine, but it's just way to dangerous a style to recommend. For instance, as soon as you add a second `T*` member you're in trouble. I couldn't possibly recommend such a design.

Comment: @Code Monkey: Oh, OK. So, in my first example, if in `new T` the constructor throws, `::operator delete(pt)` is called automatically to clean up. I should add that.

Comment: @Kerrek : If you've read the book, it's understood that the `/*...*/` is only declarations of member functions. The code listing as-shown does include all data members and the complete constructor. You're already preaching to the choir about it not being a good design (the OP said he already thought as much), but the OP was asking why the book said that _that code specifically_ is leak-proof, so to say that it isn't is just.. wrong.

Comment: @ildjarn: OK, I see, referring specifically to that constructor my answer was wrong. I changed it, hopefully it is both correct and useful now.

Comment: What does "potentially unsafe" mean?  It's either safe or it's not.  This code is safe.  If there's any unsafety, it can only be in T, and the Stack class cannot be expected, nor is it able, to account for that.  And making a single allocation is certainly not rare, it's bad practice to do otherwise.

Comment: @Kerrek : Yep, I'm satisfied anyway. ;-]

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: It's "potentially" unsafe if you expand your class, for instance to include another pointer member similar to the one you already have. If you think, "oh, `T() : p(new S) {}` is safe, so `T() : p(new S), q(new S) {}` is safe, too, then you're in trouble. (Also, if any member function throws for whatever reason (which your succcessor may implement next year), you're also in trouble.)

Comment: @Kerrek : Assuming you've not read the book, FWIW, the chapter demonstrating this code is specifically about creating classes that only perform a single function (allocation in this case) so that the pattern shown _is_ always safe. Bear in mind, the book precedes `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr`, so correctly creating your own exception-safe pointer-containing-class is a large aspect of writing exception-safe code in general. This is where answering questions with "here is what you should be doing instead" rather than just directly answering what the OP asked can be extremely confusing.

Comment: @Kerrek: "Also, if any member function throws ... you're also in trouble." -- How so?

Comment: @ildjarn: Right, I see - that makes sense. If you're actually designing the single-responsibility class, this is indeed OK. Sorry for being misleading.

Comment: @Benjamin: Err.. OK, no, my mistake - as long as the destructor gets called, it's fine. OK, I'll stop posting now, it's too late here. Sorry for all that!

Comment: Oh, No! Delete that *function-try-block* before it crashes somebody's program when new throws.

Comment: @Gene: Yes, true - cannot have to separate things throw exceptions. Editing.

Answer (score 0):

Try auto pointer for `T* v_` or any dynamic allocated resources. If following happens

```
template<class T> 
Stack<T>::Stack()
        : v_(new T[10]),
          vsize_(10),
          vused_(0)
{
    throw 0; // terminated by exception
}
```

or, there is another object in the `Stack` throw an exception when constructing, `v_` will cause memory leak. If you wrap it as `std::unique_ptr<T[]> v_` or something like this, it will be automatically freed if the construct of `Stack` terminated by an exception.

Comment: If by "auto pointer" you mean `std::auto_ptr`, using that with an array invokes undefined behavior because it calls `delete` rather than `delete[]`.

Comment: @ildjarn Excuse me "auto" here means automatic resource management, not `std::auto_ptr`. As you see I use `std::unique_ptr` in my advice, right?

Comment: Indeed, I only meant to clarify; I certainly have no problem with recommending `unique_ptr`. :-]